# Azure AD SSO for non-azure Linux VMs?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, vps, entra-id, single-sign-on

I currently have a VPS hosting for two servers with Ubuntu outside Azure network and a free azure AD plan. I see this option here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad

but it is only for azure VMs, so can I use azure ad for hosts outside of azure?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this https://cyberninjas.github.io/aad-for-linux/ with servers that outside from Azure

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature that is currently in preview and only available for VMs running in Azure.

Also note, since the feature is preview it is not to be used for production workloads as it is still being actively developed.

Comment: Yes, but is there any alternative to this solution?

Comment: You can still join Linux VMs to Active Directory. There are quite a few guides if you search it online. Here is one example https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-join-ubuntu-linux-vm you just cant use that join AAD Extension unless you are running in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Found [www.jumpcloud.com](http://www.jumpcloud.com) solutions as get solutions for SSO solution without using azure active directory

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/507690)